# RabbitMQ C# verify message was sent

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm new to RabbitMQ and trying to write to a Queue and verify the message was sent. If it fails I need to know about it.
I made a fake queue to watch it fail but no matter what I see no execptions and when I am looking for a ack I always get one. I never see the BasicNack.

I'm not even sure i'm the BasicAcks is the way to go.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare("task_queue", true, false, false, null);

                var message = ("Helllo world");
                var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                channel.ConfirmSelect();

                var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                properties.SetPersistent(true);
                properties.DeliveryMode = 2;
                channel.BasicAcks += channel_BasicAcks;
                channel.BasicNacks += channel_BasicNacks;
                //fake queue should be task_queue
                channel.BasicPublish("", "task_2queue", true, properties, body);

                channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie();

                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
            }
        }
    }

    void channel_BasicNacks(IModel model, BasicNackEventArgs args)
    {

    }

    void channel_BasicAcks(IModel model, BasicAckEventArgs args)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

For those looking for a C# answer - here is what you need.

https://rianjs.net/2013/12/publisher-confirms-with-rabbitmq-and-c-sharp

Something like this: (BasicAcks attaches an event handler - there is also BasicNacks)

```
using (var connection = FACTORY.CreateConnection())
{
    var channel = connection.CreateModel();
    channel.ExchangeDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, ExchangeType.Fanout, true);
    channel.QueueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
    channel.QueueBind(QUEUE_NAME, QUEUE_NAME, String.Empty, new Dictionary<string, object>());
     channel.BasicAcks += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    //implement ack handle
                };
    channel.ConfirmSelect();

    for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfMessages; i++)
    {
        var messageProperties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
        messageProperties.SetPersistent(true);

        var message = String.Format("{0}\thello world", i);
        var payload = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
        Console.WriteLine("Sending message: " + message);
        channel.BasicPublish(QUEUE_NAME, QUEUE_NAME, messageProperties, payload);
        channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a [Publisher Confirms](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/)

as you can read you can implement:

The transaction:

```
ch.txSelect(); <-- start transaction
ch.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME,
                            MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC,
                            "nop".getBytes());
ch.txCommit();<--commit transaction
```

The message is stored to the queue and to the disk. 
This way can be slow, if you need performance you shouldn't use it.

You can use the Streaming Lightweight Publisher Confirms, using:

```
ch.setConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {
    public void handleAck(long seqNo, boolean multiple) {
        if (multiple) {
            unconfirmedSet.headSet(seqNo+1).clear();
        } else {
            unconfirmedSet.remove(seqNo);
        }
    }
    public void handleNack(long seqNo, boolean multiple) {
        // handle the lost messages somehow
    }
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Is the light weight faster? I do need the best performance I can get. I don't really need it saved to IO but saved in the queue. If it fails I need to have fallback code.

Comment: Yes, it's faster. The transaction is very slow, you have to wait the sync disk operation,and the publish is locked until the message is stored. 
BTW Lightweight Publisher Confirms is just more complex, because you should map your messages exactly as the link, if you don't want lose your messages.

Comment: I was using channel.ConfirmSelect(); and channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie(); with was told to use the return event. I was able to see the error that way. would that be faster than ch.txSelect();/txCommit? I will be sending lots of traffic like 10k a second and looking for advise for best performance. Of course I would not open the connection each time but I've only been doing this for 1 day :)

Comment: WaitForConfirmsOrDie is faster than txcommit, anyway I suggest to use WaitForConfirmsOrDie(TIME_OUT),otherwise you risk to block forever your publish if there is some problem.

The confirm publish generally is not the good choice if you need a performance. 

So you can try to open more channel in multithreading and use WaitForConfirmsOrDie(TIME_OUT). I think you could have the right compromise. 
let me know

Comment: the stream light weight example you provided is not in c#, the op which the op is working with, could you consider editing this answer and adding a c# implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you always get the ACK for your message sent because "Every time message is delivered to Default Exchange Successfully."

PS: You are not sending message directly to Queue, Once Exchange recevis the message it gives you ACK then it route the message to all bound queue using the routing keys if any.

Comment: That is not true. In vanilla AMQP if broker accepts message (see [`basic.publish`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#basic.publish) method doc) it doesn't respond anything. Unless you are using [Publish Confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) - that is what questioner need.