# RabbitMQ Verify Message Was Sent

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

This question is already [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151705/rabbitmq-c-sharp-verify-message-was-sent) and answered. But there is a dark side in answers. My channel already supports `BasicAcks` and `BasicNacks` handlers (in a poor way):

```
Channel.BasicAcks += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Basic Ack!");
}
Channel.BasicNacks += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Basic Nack!");
}
```

I have a message that published to a queue. so I use this code to do that:

```
Channel.BasicPublish("ExchangeName", "QueueName", messageProperties, payload);
Channel.WaitForConfirmOrDie();
```

As long as `WaitForConfirmOrDie` is a void function, how can I know if message received by a queue? Or more precise, how can I implement `Ack` handlers to give me a clear state of published message in order to not send it again to queue or in the case of `BasicNack` send it again?

Comment: this is not the good way to go ? https://rianjs.net/2013/12/publisher-confirms-with-rabbitmq-and-c-sharp

Comment: yes, I visit that link. It said `You’ll have to implement event handlers for acks and nacks.` which is my question!!!

Answer (score 2):

Using the `BasicAcks` and `BasicNacks` event handlers is independent of calling `Channel.WaitForConfirmOrDie`.

`Channel.WaitForConfirmOrDie` is a convenience method that synchronously waits for message acknowledgements. So, if you publish messages one-by-one, you will wait for these acks one-by-one. As you can imagine, that is pretty inefficient.

What you should do is register for `BasicAcks` and `BasicNacks` like you have done. You should have an "acceptable number of outstanding confirms" defined. Here's one way to implement this -

- Publish up to `N` messages without an ack/nack (`N` is up to you). If the next message would exceed `N` do not continue to publish messages.
- While a message is outstanding, save it locally (in RAM or local disk). Remember that you can't be 100% sure a message is queued until you get an ack for it.
- If the message is acked, remove it from local storage and decrease the count of outstanding messages, which allows publishing to continue (if publishing is blocked). Please remember that messages can be acked in **batches**.
- If the message is nacked, you could re-try it up to a certain number of times, maybe with backoff. Once the re-try limit is exceeded, raise an application exception.

Comment: Very complete and very neat :)) @Luke is there any implementation of this? and one more request, which of these parameters `sender` or `eventArgs` has the key for `ack'd` or `nack'd` messages? How can I know this `ack` is for any message?

Comment: You should to look at the [code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client) and / or [API docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html) to answer that. [This document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms) is the guide for publisher confirms, and discusses multiple confirmations.